# How can you check if status bar is visible in Android

Tags: android

What i want to reach is, that the user can't go out of the activity except when he presses one of the supplied buttons.
I've already caught the home and back button, but when i try to remove the status bar, my problems begin.
I would like to have one of the following:

Status bar always invisible in Activity2

Status bar inaccessible, it is visible, but you can't activate it (see incoming call screen as example)

If I go for solution 1, this isn't possible if my application is running and Activity1 is showing the status bar, then Activity2 is shown under the status bar, the status bar overlays the top of Activity2
Except when I start Activity2 from another application, then Activity2 isn't showing the status bar.
[image: Status bar overlays Activity2]
[image: No Status Bar visible here]
What am I doing wrong?

Part of AndroidManifest.xml:

```
        <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="standard"
        android:name=".Activity1"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="standard"
        android:name=".Activity2"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter >
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: What you want will not work on all devices. On tablets, for example, you cannot get rid of the system bar. On the Kindle Fire, you cannot get rid of the menu bar, for similar reasons.

Comment: It will only be used on phones for now. What about blocking the Status Bar, like Android does when there is an incoming call?

Comment: AFAIK, SDK apps can't do that. A guiding principle of Android is to keep control in users' hands. An apparent guiding principle of what you're trying to do is remove control from users, for whatever reason. These principles will not co-exist especially well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to start my activity in android:launchMode="singleInstance" and in OnAttachedToWindow() i had to call this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
Now the status bar won't be shown even if other Activities in the same application do show the  status bar.

Answer (score 4):

To check status bar visibility try this code:

```
public boolean isStatusBarVisible() {
    Rect rectangle = new Rect();
    Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
    window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle);
    int statusBarHeight = rectangle.top;
    return statusBarHeight != 0;
}
```

Comment: will this be false when instantly just after setContent?

Answer (score 2):

I think this guide can be helpful for theming

http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/

Comment: That isn't the problem. I'm using the default theme's. But somehow the status bar still keeps showing if I go from Activity1 to Activity2.

Comment: did you close the activity1 after shifting to activity2 ?

Comment: This did help me up a little bit. I had to start my activity in `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` and in `OnAttachedToWindow()` i had to call `this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);`